# Rails Generators- Multiple array arguements in generator returning 'No value provided for required arguments'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, arguments, generator

ive written this generator to take multiple arrayed arguments

```
class TestScaffoldGenerator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase

  #template source
  source_root File.expand_path("../templates", __FILE__)

  #scaffold_name argument
  argument :fields, :type => :array, :required => true, :desc => "required"
  argument :validations, :type => :array, :required => true, :desc => "required"
  argument :displays_back, :type => :array, :required => true, :desc => "required"
  argument :displays_front, :type => :array, :required => true, :desc => "required"


  #gem_dependancies
  gem("haml")

  #initial generator method
  def generate_test_scaffold
    template "model.rb.erb", "app/models/#{file_name}.rb"
  end

  #private methods do get run when generator is initiated
  private

    #scaffold_name to underscore gives filename
    def file_name
      class_name.demodelize
    end

end
```

When i run 'rails g test_scaffold' i dont know how to denote the end of an arrayed argument and the begining of another...
ive tried and many more:

```
'rails g test_scaffold name:string string black white'
'rails g test_scaffold name:string, string, black, white'
'rails g test_scaffold [name:string] [string] [black] [white]'
'rails g test_scaffold [name:string], [string], [black], [white]'
'rails g test_scaffold {name:string} {string} {black} {white}'
'rails g test_scaffold {name:string}, {string}, {black}, {white}'
```

But i always get the error "No value provided for required arguments 'fields', 'validations', 'displays_back', 'displays_front'"

im really not sure how to denote an array... any suggestions?

Comment: once array is started everything afterwards is considered an instance of that array

Comment: found at http://www.slideshare.net/joshsmoore/rails-3-generators

work around is to have a single array and to pass arguements into each arra instance such as

rails g test_scaffold test name:string:string:black:white

Answer (score 2):

Run to see the help

```
rails generate test_scaffold
```

You can pass array option like this

```
rails generate test_scaffold User --fields name age
```

**User** is the scaffold name and fields can be fetched like this

```
options["fields"]
#=> ["name", "age"]
```